GridDB Real-Time Authentication Failure
I have developed a mobile application for booking truck drivers to help people with relocation. For this application, I am using two databases. MongoDB stores the necessary information about the truck drivers, such as their name, vehicle details (registration no, make, model, etc.), driver ratings, etc., while GridDB for usernames, passwords, and timestamps for real-time authentication of the users when they are signing in the application.
The reason for using two databases is to ensure that MongoDB can help store non-structured data, such as the truck drivers' information, allowing for application scalability. GridDB is used for user authentication since it is renowned for fast and efficient data retrieval. The code for authentication looks as follows:
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GSException;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStore;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStoreFactory;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.RowSet;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.TimeSeries;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.TimestampUtils;

import java.util.Date;

public class RealTimeAuthentication {

    static class TruckDriver {
        int DriverId;
        String Username;
        String PasswordHash;
        boolean IsActive;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore();

            TimeSeries<User> authenticationLogs = store.getTimeSeries("authentication_logs", TruckDriver.class);

            int DriverId = 00008;
            Date currentTime = new Date();

            Date startTime = TimestampUtils.add(currentTime, -10, com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.TimeUnit.SECOND);
            RowSet<User> DriverLogins = authenticationLogs.query("DriverId=" + DriverId + " and timestamp > '" + TimestampUtils.format(startTime) + "'").fetch();

            if (userLogins.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("User " + DriverId + " Authentication Successful.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("User " + DriverId + " Authentication Failed.");
            }

            store.close();

        } catch (GSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

I allowed the system to wait 10 seconds for GridDB to authenticate and allow the user to log into the application as shown above.
The application was working fine for a few number of users; however, when this number started to increase to a few hundred and thousands, it began to receive authentication error, which is shown as follows:
Authentication Failed.
ERROR:Database Connection Error

I increased the storeMemoryLimit from 1024MB to 2048MB in gs_node.json as the documentation suggested, to resolve the issue, but it did not help.
$ cat /var/lib/gridstore/conf/gs_node.json

{
        "dataStore":{
                "dbPath":"/var/lib/gridstore/data",
                "backupPath":"/var/lib/gridstore/backup",  
                "storeMemoryLimit":"2048MB",
                "storeWarmStart":true,
                "concurrency":1,
                "logWriteMode":1,
                "persistencyMode":"NORMAL",
}

Kindly suggest what this issue could be. I appreciate any help you can provide.
